Unable to publish & run a scoped NPM package for use with NPX
I've created a scoped package for use with NPX. It works as I expect when running locally using npm link to test it, but after publishing the package, it won't install it.
My package.json is as follows:
{
  "name": "@myscope/mod-hook01",
  "description": "omitted for brevity",
  "version": "1.9.1",
  "bin": {
    "mod-hook01": "src/index.js"
  },
  ..
}

After installing, when I run it, I get this:
➜ npx @myscope/mod-hook01
sh: mod-hook01: command not found

I checked the NPM bin folder and sure enough, it's not there. I believe I'm doing everything correctly, but clearly not... anything stands out?

Found my error... following up as it wasn't obvious from the errors so sharing for others who may run into this...
I was deploying a beta version (via dist-tag=next), but I was trying to install the latest. When I changed to npx @myscope/mod-hook01@next, it worked as expected.
